# Format currency with indian suffixes IOS

Tags: ios

I want to display the number 13456 as 13.456K,3456789 as 34.56L.Is there any formatter in IOS to convert with K(thousand),L(Lakh),M(Million),C(Crore) suffixes?

Comment: What are K, L and C and what is there relationship?  Is there a simple calculation to convert between them?

Comment: K-thousand(10^3),L-Lakh(10^5),C-crore(10^7)

Comment: There is no formatter for those suffixes but you can create your own formatter by using [Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no library or sdk in `iOS` for shortening or converting currency using abbreviations like *K (thousand)*, *M (million)* similarly *L (100 thousand)*, *C (10 million)*, etc., as these abbreviations are different in different countries and regions.

You'll have to convert the number according to category in which your number falls and using `NSNumberFormatter` with `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` you can format your number according to your requirement.

You can use following code for converting currency amount according to your requirement:

```
float shortenedAmount = actualAmount;
NSString *suffix = @"";
if(currency >= 10000000.0f) {
    suffix = @"C";
    shortenedAmount /= 10000000.0f;
}
else if(currency >= 1000000.0f) {
    suffix = @"M";
    shortenedAmount /= 1000000.0f;
}
else if(currency >= 100000.0f) {
    suffix = @"L";
    shortenedAmount /= 100000.0f;
}
else if(currency >= 1000.0f) {
    suffix = @"K";
    shortenedAmount /= 1000.0f;
}

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:shortenedAmount]];

NSString *requiredString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", numberAsString, suffix];
```

Answer (score 0):

IOS does not provide any formatter for those suffix.

> You can make your own formatter using extension. Extensions will add new functionality to your program and it would definitely work :)

Link to [extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below custom method -

```
 -(NSString *)stringFormating:(int)numValue
{
    NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numValue];

    if ([valueString length]>7)
    {
        NSString *strsecondPart= [valueString substringFromIndex:[valueString length] -7];

        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%dC",[valueString substringToIndex:[valueString length] -7],[strsecondPart intValue]];

    }
    else if ([valueString length]>5)
    {

        NSString *strsecondPart= [valueString substringFromIndex:[valueString length] -5];

        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%dL",[valueString substringToIndex:[valueString length] -5],[strsecondPart intValue]];

    }
    else if ([valueString length]>3)
    {

        NSString *strsecondPart= [valueString substringFromIndex:[valueString length] -3];

        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%dK",[valueString substringToIndex:[valueString length] -3],[strsecondPart intValue]];

    }


    return valueString;

}

NSLog(@"%@", [self stringFormating:100000]);
```

output will be 1.0L

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self stringFormating:123456]);
```

output will be 1.23456L

Comment: That's a funny way to manipulate a number (by funny I mean inefficient and counter intuitive).  You also have multiple `return` statements for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift implementation:
Convert NumberFormatter (NSNumberFormatter) in Swift to Make Currency in Indian Numbering Format.

```
extension Int {
        func withCommas() -> String {
            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
           numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_IN")      // English (Indian) locale with english language is used
            return numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:self))!
        }
    }



//Easy to use:--
            let strValue = "64567890"
            let intValue = (strValue! as NSString).integerValue
            print(intValue.withCommas())                   // 6,45,67,890
//             cell.lbl.text = intValue.withCommas()
```